# Change width and height of mat-expansion indicator

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to change the width and height of the mat indicator. According to other answers to similar questions all you have to do is change the border width and padding. However it works when I use the console inspect mode but in my css the changes are not reflecting. What am I missing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8yxted?file=styles.css

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0 !important;
  content: '' !important;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your css is not being used. I know it's deprecated, but have you tryed using ::ng-deep?

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0 !important;
  content: '' !important;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that did it? do you know why it is not being use. and also what does ng-deep do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your style in "`style.css`" file? It should work if you put your updated style "`style.css`" file.

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0 !important;
  content: '' !important;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

See the updated stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8yxted-uvnyat?file=styles.css

Comment: hey yeah that works. But do you know why I can't see the local .css for that componnt instead of the globel style.css